# How to concatenate pandas dataframe columns into iterable lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a pandas dataframe with about 200 columns. Columns 31-73 look something like this:

```
31   32   33
NaN  NaN  Z
X    NaN  Z
NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  Y    Z
```

What I hope to return is a new column that looks (something) like this:

```
new_col
[Z]
[X,Z]
[]
[Y,Z]
```

I'm close, but not quite there. This code:

```
data['new_col'] = data.ix[:, 30:73].fillna('').apply(lambda row: ','.join(map(str, row)), axis=1)
```

returns this:

```
new_col
,,Z
,X,,Z
,,,
,,Y,Z
```

How can I exclude unnecessary delimiters from the new concatenated list?

Comment: Wait, so do you want each element of the column to be a list or a string?

Comment: Indeed are you after the output from my answer or a comma separated string of values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have an errant value `Nan` which I'm assuming is `NaN`, anyway this should work:

```
In [24]:
df.apply(lambda x: [','.join(x.dropna())], axis=1)

Out[24]:
0      [Z]
1    [X,Z]
2       []
3    [Y,Z]
dtype: object
```

So in your case:

```
data['new_col'] = data.apply(lambda x: [','.join(x.dropna())], axis=1)
```

should work.

Comment: @samthebrand: just to be clear, having a column containing lists is generally recommended against to begin with, but a column containing lists, each of which has one element which is a string, isn't a very pandorable approach.

Comment: @DSM I think I see what you're saying (just ran into an "unhashable type: 'list'" warning). I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing (as usual), but hoping to eventually iterate over the dataframe depending upon whether `new_col` includes `Z` or `X` or a combination of values that might exist in that column. Does it make sense to store these "lists" as a different data type?

Comment: You could put them in a set I suppose, that would allow you to test for membership

Comment: Hmm, @EdChum I'm having a little trouble figuring out how I might modify your snippet so that it returns sets. Any chance you can provide a hint?

Comment: like this: `df.apply(lambda x: {','.join(x.dropna())}, axis=1)` so in your case: `data['new_col'] = data.apply(lambda x: {','.join(x.dropna())}, axis=1)`